# Смена способа отображения элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию соответствующих кнопок, менялся способ отображения элементов на странице - в виде списка и в виде плиток? Есть какой-то плагин?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, это делается изменением класса с помощью js для элемента, который оборачивает ваш список.

Изменяя класс вы сможете применять различные css правила для вложенных элементов.